# How can Vuelidate be used to limit the min length of a text input?

Tags: javascript, validation, vue.js, text, vuelidate

How can Vuelidate be used to limit the min length of a text input? This is a child of a child component. In the code, minLength = 4. It appears that one must create methods to handle the resulting Vuelidate object in order to handle any form errors? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

`console.log(this.$v.message_text.$params.minLength.min);` outputs `4`.

Vue component where Vuelidate validation is taking place:

```
<template>
        <div>
        <input type="text" name="message_text" id="message_text"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="New message"
            v-model="message"
            @keyup.enter.prevent="sendMessage">
        </div>
</template>

<script>

import { required, minLength } from "vuelidate/lib/validators";

export default {
    props: ['activeChannel', 'username'],

    data() {
        return {
            message: '',
            message_text: ''
        };
    },


    validations: {
        message_text: {
          required,
          minLength: minLength(4)
        },
    },



    methods: {
        sendMessage() {
            let endpoint = `/channels/${this.activeChannel}/messages`;

            let data = {
                username: this.username,
                message: this.message
            };

            axios.post(endpoint, data);

            this.message = '';

            console.log(this.$v.message_text.$params.minLength.min);

        }
    }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

The following lines are present in main app.js:

```
import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate'
Vue.use(Vuelidate)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found here: `https://jsfiddle.net/b5v4faqf/` 
A method must be created to handle the form errors Vuelidate identifies.:

```
<template>
        <div>
        <input type="text"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="New message."
            v-model="$v.message.$model"
            :class="status($v.message)"
            @keyup.enter.prevent="sendMessage">
            <pre>{{ $v }}</pre>
        </div>
</template>

<script>

import { required, minLength } from "vuelidate/lib/validators";

export default {
    props: ['activeChannel', 'username'],

    data() {
        return {
            message: '',
        };
    },


    validations: {
        message: {
          required,
          minLength: minLength(4)
        },
    },



    methods: {

        status(validation) {
            return {
            error: validation.$error,
            dirty: validation.$dirty
            }
        },

        sendMessage() {

            // if its still pending or an error is returned do not submit
            this.$v.message.$touch();
            if (this.$v.message.$error) return;

            let endpoint = `/channels/${this.activeChannel}/messages`;

            let data = {
                username: this.username,
                message: this.message
            };

            axios.post(endpoint, data);

            this.message = '';

        }
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

input {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.dirty {
  border-color: #5A5;
  background: #EFE;
}

.dirty:focus {
  outline-color: #8E8;
}

.error {
  border-color: red;
  background: #FDD;
}

.error:focus {
  outline-color: #F99;
}


</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following and read up a little on vuelidate docs as you start to use it. I think the message_text data property is redundant or it is not clear what you intend to do with it.

```
<template>
        <div>
        <input type="text" name="message_text" id="message_text"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="New message."
            v-model="$v.message.$model"
            @keyup.enter.prevent="sendMessage">
        </div>
</template>

<script>

import { validationMixin } from 'vuelidate'
    import {
        required,
        maxLength
    } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'


export default {
    props: ['activeChannel', 'username'],

    data() {
        return {
            message: '',
            message_text: ''
        };
    },


    validations: {
        message: {
          required,
           maxLength: maxLength(10)
        },
    },



    methods: {
        sendMessage() {
            let endpoint = `/channels/${this.activeChannel}/messages`;

            let data = {
                username: this.username,
                message: this.message
            };

            axios.post(endpoint, data);

            this.message = '';
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I still don't understand why you are trying to validate message_text when you are binding the input to message. There is no input bound to message_text. Vue doesn't care about the name and id of any input element. Also you have to check for errors in sendMessage before submitting

Comment: Right, I answered my own question. Thanks